# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: error.JSON is not a function. (In 'error.JSON()', 'error.JSON' is undefined)]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, react-native, axios

I am trying to connect the front end with the back end using Axios as the API connector

When I followed the documentation of the Axios it gives me this error. However, when I try to test it on Postman it works perfectly fine.

[The error that occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePir8.png)

**Backed code working perfectly fine on postman:**
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cat3.png)

**Entry registered on MongoDB Atlas:**
[MongoDB Atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaZe5.png)

Back-end:

**App.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

app.use(express.json());

const port = 5000;


mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to database");
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});


require("./userDetails");

const User = mongoose.model("UserInfo");

//Password handler

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { Router } = require("next/router");

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if (name == "" || email == "" || password == "") {
    res.json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: "Empty input fields!",
    });
  } else if (!/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(name)) {
    res.json({
      status: "FAILED",
      message: "Invalid name input",
    });
  } else if (!/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(email)) {
    res.json({
      status: "FAILED",
      message: "Invalid email input",
    });
  } else if (password.length < 8) {
    res.json({
      status: "FAILED",
      message: "Password must be at least 8 or more characters",
    });
  } else {
    User.find({ email })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.length) {
          res.json({
            status: "Failed",
            message: "User with the provided email already exists!",
          });
        } else {
          const saltRounds = 10;
          bcrypt
            .hash(password, saltRounds)
            .then((hashedPassword) => {
              const newUser = new User({
                uname: name,
                email,
                password: hashedPassword,
              });

              newUser
                .save()
                .then((result) => {
                  res.json({
                    status: "Success",
                    message: "SignUp Succesfull",
                    data: result,
                  });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  res.json({
                    status: "Failed",
                    message: "An error occured while saving account!",
                  });
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              res.json({
                status: "Failed",
                message: "An error occured while hashing password!",
              });
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({
          status: "FAILED",
          message: "An error occurred while checking for existing user!",
        });
      });
  }

});

app.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (email == "" || password == "") {
    res.json({
      status: "Failed",
      message: "Empty inputs",
    });
  } else {
    User.find({ email })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          const hashedPassword = data[0].password;
          bcrypt
            .compare(password, hashedPassword)
            .then((result) => {
              if (result) {
                res.json({
                  status: "SUCCESS",
                  message: "Signin successful",
                  data: data,
                });
              } else {
                res.json({
                  status: "FAILED",
                  message: "Invalid password entered!",
                });
              }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              res.json({
                status: "FAILED",
                message: "An error orccured while comparing the passords",
              });
            });
        } else {
          res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Invalid inputs",
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.json({
          status: "Failed",
          message: "An error occurred while checking for existing user!",
        });
      });
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

**api/client.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:5000" });
```

Front-end:

**Login.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

// formik
import { Formik } from 'formik';

//icons
import { Octicons, Ionicons, Fontisto } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import {
  StyledContainer,
  InnerContainer,
  PageLogo,
  PageTitle,
  SubTitle,
  StyledFormArea,
  LeftIcon,
  StyledInputLabel,
  StyledTextInput,
  RightIcon,
  StyledButton,
  ButtonText,
  Colors,
  Line,
  MsgBox,
  ExtraView,
  ExtraText,
  TextLink,
  TextLinkContent,
} from './../components/style';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

//colors
const { brand, darkLight, primary } = Colors;

//keyboard avoid view
import KeyboardAvoidingWrapper from '../components/KeyboardAvoidingWrapper';

// API client
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [hidePassword, setHidePassword] = useState(true);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const [messageType, setMessageType] = useState();

  const handleLogin = (credentials, setSubmitting) => {
    handleMessage(null);
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/signin';

    axios
      .post(url, credentials)
      .then((response) => {
        const result = response.data;
        const { message, status, data } = result;

        if (status !== 'SUCCESS') {
          handleMessage(message, status);
        } else {
          navigation.navigate('Welcome', { ...data[0] });
        }
        setSubmitting(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.JSON());
        setSubmitting(false);
        handleMessage('An error occurred. Check your network and try again');
      });
  };

  const handleMessage = (message, type = 'FAILED') => {
    setMessage(message);
    setMessageType(type);
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
      <StyledContainer>
        <StatusBar style="dark" />
        <InnerContainer>
          <PageLogo resizeMode="cover" source={require('./../assets/Logo.png')} />
          <PageTitle>Umbrellah</PageTitle>
          <SubTitle>Account Login</SubTitle>

          <Formik
            initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
              if (values.email == '' || values.password == '') {
                handleMessage('Please fill all the fields');
                setSubmitting(false);
              } else {
                handleLogin(values, setSubmitting);
              }
            }}
          >
            {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, isSubmitting }) => (
              <StyledFormArea>
                <MyTextinput
                  label="Email Address"
                  icon="mail"
                  placeholder="yourEmail@example.com"
                  placeholderTextColor={darkLight}
                  onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                  value={values.email}
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                />

                <MyTextinput
                  label="Password"
                  icon="lock"
                  placeholder="* * * * * * * * * * * * * *"
                  placeholderTextColor={darkLight}
                  onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                  value={values.password}
                  secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
                  isPassword={true}
                  hidePassword={hidePassword}
                  setHidePassword={setHidePassword}
                />

                <MsgBox type={messageType}>{message}</MsgBox>
                {!isSubmitting && (
                  <StyledButton onPress={handleSubmit}>
                    <ButtonText>Login</ButtonText>
                  </StyledButton>
                )}

                {isSubmitting && (
                  <StyledButton disabled={true}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={primary} />
                  </StyledButton>
                )}

                <Line />
                <StyledButton google={true} onPress={handleSubmit}>
                  <Fontisto name="google" color={primary} size={25} />
                  <ButtonText google={true}>Sign in with Google</ButtonText>
                </StyledButton>

                <ExtraView>
                  <ExtraText>Don't have an account already? </ExtraText>
                  <TextLink onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
                    <TextLinkContent>Signup</TextLinkContent>
                  </TextLink>
                </ExtraView>
              </StyledFormArea>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </InnerContainer>
      </StyledContainer>
    </KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
  );
};

const MyTextinput = ({ label, icon, isPassword, hidePassword, setHidePassword, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <LeftIcon>
        <Octicons name={icon} size={30} color={brand} />
      </LeftIcon>
      <StyledInputLabel> {label} </StyledInputLabel>
      <StyledTextInput {...props} />
      {isPassword && (
        <RightIcon onPress={() => setHidePassword(!hidePassword)}>
          <Ionicons name={hidePassword ? 'md-eye-off' : 'md-eye'} size={30} color={darkLight} />
        </RightIcon>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

**api/client.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I managed to find the solution for the issues.

First of all huge thanks to Mostafa for his answer.

https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

**Change JSON to toJSON:**

**Before:**

```
.catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.JSON());
        setSubmitting(false);
        handleMessage('An error occurred. Check your network and try again');
      });
```

**After:**

```
  .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.toJSON());
        setSubmitting(false);
        handleMessage('An error occured. Check your network and try again');
      });
```

**Change localhost to your IP Address:**

**Before:**

```
const url = 'http://localhost:5000/signin';
```

**After:**

```
const url = 'http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/signin';
```

Answer (score 0):

Each tool and library may have a different structure for response. If you're using Axios you must follow the Axios structure.

The error is thrown from this part of the code, which you're trying to use `error.JSON`:

```js
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error.JSON());
  setSubmitting(false);
  handleMessage('An error occured. Check your network and try again');
})
```

If you want to handle errors in Axios, then you need to read about it in their [official documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors).

e.g:

```js
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```